# How to install mod_ssl for Apache

Tags: apache, https, security-certificate, httpd

I have installed Apache httpd a while ago and have recently come back to it to try setup SSL and get it serving several different tomcat servers.

At the moment I have two completely separate tomcat instances serving up to slightly different versions (one for Dev and one for demo say) my web app to two different ports;
    `mydomain.com:8081` and `mydomain.com:8082`

I've successfully (back in Jan) used mod_jk to get httpd to serve those same tomcat instances to `http://www.mydomain.com:8090/dev` and `http://www.mydomain.com:8090/dem`o  (8090 cos I've got another app running on 8080 via Jetty at this stage) using the following code in httpd.conf;

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel debug

<VirtualHost *:8090>
    JkMount /devd* tomcatDev
    JkMount /demo* tomcatDemo
</VirtualHost>
```

What I'm not trying to do is enable SSL

I've added the following to httpd.conf

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    JkMount /dev* tomcatDev
    JkMount /demo* tomcatDemo
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/httpd/conf/localhost.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/httpd/conf/keystore.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to restart Apache with "apachectl restart" (yes after shutting down that other app I mentioned so it doesn't toy with https connections) I continuously get the error;

**"Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration. httpd not running, trying to start"**

I've looked in the httpd/modules dir and indeed there is no mod_ssl, only mod_jk.so and httpd.exp.

I've tried using yum to install mod_ssl, it says its already installed. Indeed I can locate mod_ssl.so in /usr/lib/httpd/modules but this is NOT the path to where I've installed httpd which is /opt/httpd and in fact /usr/lib/httpd contains nothing but the modules dir.

Can anyone tell me how to install mod_ssl properly for my installed location of httpd so I can get past this error:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line to actually load mod_ssl needs to be added to your Apache config somewhere -- on Debian/Ubuntu, you would just do `sudo a2enmod ssl`, but I don't know the RedHat/Fedora/CentOS equivalent. You need a line like:

```
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Comment: Ha, I knew it would be something simple like that! Cheers